# understanding logic behind databases

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Lets say I have a database where I have a table **subject** which has **idSubject** and **Subject** as it's columns both of them varchar with length of 20, **idSubject** being autoincrement. All id's are autoincrement.

Then I have another table that is called **Unit**. Now **Unit** has **idUnit**(int), **evaluation**(varchar), **learnUnit**(varchar), **percent**(int) and **dueDate**(date).

subject table is connected to unit table as one to many.

I keep adding more units to a subject, but when I want to change to another subject, how would I be able to visualize all the information gathered for only one subject?

The logic behind this is what I don't understand. How would I do an SQL query to find all the information for one subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a column in the unit table which contains the `idsubject`. So, many rows will have same value for this column, which corresponds to their corresponding `idsubject`.

How will you do that? Easy.

During insertion, also insert the `idsubject` in the unit table. This will give you an idea of what subjects you have to deal with. Now, there is an option called `group by` in sql, which can help you filter the units of same subjects.

```
SELECT idSubjects, commands(column_name(s))
FROM Unit
GROUP BY idSubject;
```

or

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM Unit
Where idSubject operator value;
```

So, this is how you can use these two tables: one have only subjects and the other containing all the units for all those subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, how to resolve this, is that you create a third table where you create the connection between the unit and the subjects. You may do it like said before, to add a column referencing on the idSubject, but it's a more cleaner and compfortible way to create a third table named like "UnitsToSubject" for example.

There you just may have three columns like:

"ID": For the internal table "UnitsToSubject" to reference.

"SubjectID": The ID of your subject.

"UnitID": The ID of your unit.

With that way you can easily change the connection between subjects and units.